# Reasons to use an analog temperature sensor instead of a digital one

Tags: digital-logic, sensor, analog, temperature

I'm designing a microcontroller-based system that includes a thermostat.

When choosing which temperature sensor to use, I noticed that analog ones have more or less the same power consumption, the same temperature range and the same cost as digital ones.

Aside from possibly having a higher resolution ADC on the MCU than the one included in the digital sensor chip, are there any advantages in using an analog temperature sensor over a digital one?

Comment: A thermocouple will operate at massively higher temperatures than silicon would ever survive.

Comment: A thermocouple will also operate at massively lower temperatures than the silicon would ever hope to operate (T, E or K types).

Comment: Get a datasheet for a typical example of either type of temperature sensor. Then compare and see that above two comments are true.

Comment: The price of sensor itself maybe quite the same, but what about analog front end and ADC?

Comment: A Ge RTD will operate accurately at lower temperatures than any digital sensor (or thermocouple) will.

Comment: I can take a type K thermocouple, heat it to yellow heat, quench it in ice water, hit it with a mallet to flatten it and it will still be accurate. Try that with a chip sensor and compare.. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analog temperature sensors are easier in general to attach to the end of wires to make a temperature probe. On the other hand digital temperature sensors are in IC packages that are generally designed to be placed on a circuit board. This means that the probe type of sensor till typically have less thermal mass and be easier to couple to the medium being measured. A digital type IC sensor can be mounted on a small probe board on the end of a cable but it has more thermal mass and the IC package material does isolate the sensor some from the measured medium.

There are some digital IC temperature sensors that you can put on your MCU board but then support the attachment of a diode used as a temperature sensor. The diode is much easier to remote as a probe if that is needed. The ADT7476 is one example of this type of sensor.